# Dynamic paths for postgres file_fdw (csv)

Tags: postgresql, csv, foreign-data

I've got a postgres database which relies on the use of [foreign tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) to support the loading of large data sets based on user-provided (system sanitized) tables. I'd use `COPY`, but the tables loaded on a recurring (but non-daily) cycle and have complex load parameters which we've built into functions (using a combination of `UPDATE WHERE`, `DELETE WHERE`, `TRUNCATE AND INSERT`, `INSERT, ON CONFLICT`)

The process works well, and is stable.  While I'm generally happy with it, I realize that it opens up the possibility that at some point the file paths specified in the `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` command will change (e.g. from `/home/postgres/path_primary/table.csv` to `/home/postgres/path_secondary/table.csv`).

**My question:** Is there a way to point the base of the file path to a non-static value to abstract that change? Or would I be better off writing a script to collect the list of foreign tables, drop them, and rebuild the DDL with new filepath arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: Is there a way to point the base of the file path to a non-static value to abstract that change? Or would I be better off writing a script to collect the list of foreign tables, drop them, and rebuild the DDL with new filepath arguments?

You can point to a symlink. However, I wouldn't. I would keep things running just the way you're doing it now. What's the reason to do that? I imagine under any reasonable load the DDL is not an issue. But, it may be worth experimenting and reporting back.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me, I appreciate the feedback.